# Figuring out which iBeacon is closer to the Android device using TX power

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am using iBeacons in a small area, and with overlapping signals, all the beacons appear as near, even when I turn the TX power down. In order to identify which zone I am in based on the closeness of the nearest beacon, I wrote some code to determine the closest beacon to the Android device.

```
    @Override
public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
     iBeaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons, Region region) {

                int locMinor = 0;
                String location = "Empty";
                if (iBeacons.size()== 1) {//This loop looks for which zone the single beacon detected belongs to.

                    locMinor = iBeacons.iterator().next().getMinor();
                    logToDisplay("I'm in the if loop");
                    switch(locMinor){
                    case 12110 : location ="Window";
                    break;
                    case 61390 : location ="Shelves";
                    break;
                    case 63911 : location ="LaserCutter";
                    break;
                    }
                    logToDisplay(location);
                }
                else if (iBeacons.size()==2){//This loop compares 2 beacons and chooses the closer one
                    double array1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                    for (int i = 0; i<4;){
                        double temp = (double)iBeacons.iterator().next().getMinor();
                        array1[i] = temp;
                        i++;
                        array1[i] = iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();
                        i++;
                    }
                    double minDist = Math.min(array1[1], array1[3]);
                    if(minDist == array1[1]){
                        locMinor = (int)array1[0];
                    }
                    else if (minDist == array1[3]){
                        locMinor = (int)array1[2];
                    }
                    switch(locMinor){
                    case 12110 : location ="Window";
                    break;
                    case 61390 : location ="Shelves";
                    break;
                    case 63911 : location ="LaserCutter";
                    break;
                    }
                    logToDisplay(location);
                }
                else if (iBeacons.size()==3){//This loop compares 3 beacons and chooses the closer one
                    double array1[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
                    for (int i = 0; i<6;){
                        double temp = (double)iBeacons.iterator().next().getMinor();
                        array1[i] = temp;
                        i++;
                        array1[i] = iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy();
                        i++;
                    }
                    double minDist = Math.min(array1[1], array1[3]);
                    double minDist2 = Math.min(minDist, array1[5]);
                    if(minDist2 == array1[1]){
                        locMinor = (int)array1[0];
                    }
                    else if (minDist2 == array1[3]){
                        locMinor = (int)array1[2];
                    }
                    else if (minDist2 == array1[5]){
                        locMinor = (int) array1[4];
                    }

                    else if (locMinor == 61390)
                    switch(locMinor){
                    case 12110 : location ="Window";
                    break;
                    case 61390 : location ="Shelves";
                    break;
                    case 63911 : location ="LaserCutter";
                    break;
                    }
                    logToDisplay(location);
                }

            } 

            });

            try {
                iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region ("sOhf", "F8914AB4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".toLowerCase(), 24866, 63911));
                iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region ("XiFb", "F8914AB4-xxxx-xxxx-8024-xxxxxxxxxxxx".toLowerCase(), 36889, 61390));
                iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region ("G5Ig", "F8914AB4-xxxx-xxxx-8024-xxxxxxxxxxxx".toLowerCase(), 24218, 12110));

                logToDisplay ("I am inside the startRangingBeaconsInRegion");
            } 

            catch (RemoteException e) {   }

}
```

However, when I run the code, it seems that it is stuck in the Try Catch statement. Is there anything that I am doing wrong, like in the case switch? I'm not sure if i can use such numbers in a case switch. Or is this a wrong way to use the beacons? Please advise.

Comment: The switch statement looks OK, so it may be a hole in the other logic.  ICan you add more debug output and let us know what you see when you run it?

Comment: Also, here is sample logic from one of my programs for calculating the closest beacon in a museum guide app:https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/museum-guide-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/radiusnetworks/museumguide/VisibleMuseumItems.java

Comment: I've tried debugging the app, and the output on my phone is simply "I am inside the startRangingBeaconsInRegion". I added breakpoints to the start of the if statements, but it seems like it doesn't go into didRangeBeaconsInRegion.

Comment: Doing more digging, and I found that in the loop, iBeacons.iterator().next().getMinor() or iBeacons.iterator().next().getAccuracy is not moving to the next detected beacon. Instead, the same beacon just gets called up. Any advise on how to resolve this?